# Is UTF8 urlEncodedFormat in CFML (BlueDragon JX 7.1) broken?

Tags: utf-8, coldfusion, character-encoding, cfml, bluedragon

I have a small file containing the `é` char and a linebreak. The file is encoded in UTF-8.

When I write `urlEncodedFormat(trim(content))` it yields `"%C3%A9"` and this is **correct**.

Now, `urlEncodedFormat` accepts a second argument, according to the docs : "The character encoding in which the string is encoded.".

So, my string is encoded as UTF-8, so if I provide `'utf-8'` it should yield the same thing.

But not at all :

`urlEncodedFormat(trim(content), 'utf-8')` yields `"%C3%83%C2%A9"`.

It works using a iso-8859-1 file, passing this encoding as a second argument does not change the output.

This is how I read the file :

```
<cffile action="read" file=#filename# variable="content"/>
```

So why is that ? I can't figure out how encoding works in this language.

Thank you very much.